# Storing user attributes in a user table

Tags: database, database-normalization

When making a database with users (that have attributes such as religion), what is the best way to store those attributes and the possible values for them?

Here are the methods and problems:

method 1:  If you have a user, say a Christian, you could store this value in the users table under a column called "Religion". The problem with this method is that there would be many, many occurences of the word "Christian" in the users table, which seems redundant to me.

problem 1:   Also, with this method, there is nowhere in the database that all possible values are stored like "Buddhist", "Muslim", etc. This would make populating a dropdown difficult if not impossible.

method 2:   Another method I came up with is to index these values. Change the "Religion" column in the users table to "ReligionID" and number them. Christian = 1, Muslim = 2, etc. Then have a foreign key relationship to another table with the lookup values.

problem 2:    The problem with this method is that there will have to be many, many tables linked to the users table with foreign key values for other similar attributes, like eye color. Although populating a dropdown list would be easy with this method, this seems to create too many joins and seems like an ugly way to design this database.

What is the best way to do this? Feel free to come up with your own methods if these ones are not optimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

database normalization is all about tradeoffs. The way I look at it, I always start with as close to [3nf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) as possible (ie. method 2). When either the size of my data, or my performance requirements change ... I consider denormalizing (ie. method 1).

when you get to that point, your applications need to take responsibility for data integrity ... depending on how much control you have over the clients of the database, that may or may not be easy. But that's why you get paid the big bucks ;-)

Comment: Great answer. I'm looking for as much long-term forethought from the get-go. What would you think about storing a table of "User Options" and making every attributes a record in that table? What do you think would be the most efficient, long-term method?

Comment: That is one option that I've used in the past. It's super flexible, but trust me when I say that the effort will more than likely not pay off. Performance will be terrible if you want to join into that table, and it will be confusing for new devs joining the team to understand the layout. Efficient and Long-Term aren't always on speaking terms with each other :-P The way I look at it, do things the "proper" way now, and only worry about making them more scalable if they become a problem (of course, if you *know* you have certain perf requirements, plan for them up front)

Comment: Thanks. It seems as if while normalizing a table, I'm already in the stages of denormalizing it for performance right away. In following for rules of normalization, would the "User Options" table be the most normalized?

Comment: no ... having a user options table can easily end up breaking data integrity. I'll give you an example. Many people that use that pattern, end up using the same "options" table for either many columns in one table, or many columns in different tables. So they add an "optionType" field to say what field a subset of options apply to, then you end up with rules (which are usually managed by the application) where you can only enter the range of option IDs that correspond to a certain optionType. Then someone inserts the wrong value somewhere, and your reports go to hell. #FromExperience

Comment: Is storing multiple, repeating values in a column for users, like "Christian" (for many users) considered a normal form failure?

Comment: This borders on unhelpful, but the only real answer here is "it depends". Like @normalocity said, that usually depends on whether you allow arbitrary entries, or if you control the values. But what you'll find is that many databases will have a table, with foreign key constraints and all those great data integrity tools. Then there will be a reporting database that denormalizes the heck out of all the data for fast reporting. So "it depends" on whether you need to optimize for writes, or reads. Don't focus so much on the "proper" answer, just what makes sense for you right now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another answer here just to contribute to the discussion. In a comment, you  mentioned that you may have as many as 10-15 joins that you would require to get all the display names for the foreign keys.

One technique I've often used to work around this is to join on the client. Here's what I mean:

1. Query your table with no joins ... this means you'll just get IDs for many of your values.
2. While you're displaying your data, anytime you need to display a text-friendly value try to grab it from cache.
3. If it's not there, grab the whole lookup table right then and there, and cache it for an hour, or a day (whatever makes sense).
4. The cached value could be as simple as a Dictionary, so you can grab the dictionary from cache, and pull out the string description for display.

It's counterintuitive ... but you can get the best of both worlds here. Great data integrity from a nicely designed database, and great performance because you're not doing any joins on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 will work fine if your form allows arbitrary entries (i.e. faiths that you haven't already thought of, where a person can enter their own faith, or other free-form text).

Method 2 will work fine if there's a reason you only want to support a set list of faiths, and/or you want to have control over when new faiths are added.

You can start with method 1, and convert it to method 2 later, should you feel it's appropriate. Depends on your app, how its used, and how it affects performance and integrity: questions which you may not know the answer to until people really start to use it regularly.

Comment: Yes, everything you said is true. My focus however is on database efficiency. I want to use the most efficient method. I'm not concerned about whether or not the user can add their own attribute values. The point is that with lookup tables, that will lead to a lot of additional tables and foreign keys and joins. Without them, a lot of redundant data will be stored in the user table.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with a little join here and there ;-) put a view on it and have your apps display from the view and you won't have to worry about joining as often (from a query writing perspective)

Comment: It's not one join that I'm concerend about. In populating a user's information, there may be as many as 10-15 joins. That seems like join-overkill.

Comment: yeah, that is a little excessive. However, if your caching policy is aggressive enough you can mitigate that by only querying (and thus joining) when your app layer gets a cache miss.

Comment: The point is you can't predict real-world performance issues before you hit them with real-world users. Neither method you proposed is really a bad one, so either one should work fine, and it's going to come down to how your app actually gets used. It's so easy to switch from one to the other, why not just pick one and get on with it? I'm sure you've got lots of other important decisions to make about your app than this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the attribute of a user by using a database field type of enum() to set a list of religions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html. This field will only accept the values you specify when creating the column. It also makes it easy to add more types by modifying the column in your database.

In PHP, you can populate a drop down by using this function from http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_enum to get an array of enum values to loop over:

```
function enum_select( $table , $field ){
    $query = " SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table` LIKE '$field' ";
    $result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( 'error getting enum field ' . mysql_error() );
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_NUM );
    #extract the values
    #the values are enclosed in single quotes
    #and separated by commas
    $regex = "/'(.*?)'/";
    preg_match_all( $regex , $row[1], $enum_array );
    $enum_fields = $enum_array[1];
    return( $enum_fields );
}
```

Comment: could you populate a drop-down list with the enum values? where are the enum values stored?

Comment: To clarify, the function provided above extracts the enum values into the returned array so you can loop over the array in your select code.

Comment: and if you're using sql server, you can use a check constraint that checks for the expected values